# Access denied for user 'sol0nig_User'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, database

im stuck to this ijust just not able to find why this error is coomming. suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

MySQL_class: Database Error occured!

```
CODE: 1045
DESC: Access denied for user 'sol0nig_User'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
FILE: index.php
QCNT: 0
INFO: Connect(): Connection to localhost failed!
```

Please inform support@intouchgroup.in about this problem.
PHP v5.3.28 / MySQL Class v0.36

Comment: a) the password is incorrect b) the user does not have permission on the DB you are trying to connect to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct database details in the connection such as user/password.

Comment: I checked it these details are right but how can i check these details